# Python 3: pass type as function parameter

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

How can I pass `int` or `str` as function parameters in Python?

Example:

```
def fn(type:<arg typing here>):
    # do something

output = fn(type=int)
```

Example 2 from `django commands`:

```
parser.add_argument(
        'years', type=int, help="Determines how many years of fake data to generate.")
```

Comment: What is "django commands"? A book? A command-line thing? A web page? A web site? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the typing declaration, your code should already work.  For typing the parameter, you could use `typing.Type`:

```
from typing import Type

def fn(type: Type):
    # do something
```

However, you might not want to use the builtin name `type` as the name of a parameter.  Some might prefer something like this:

```
from typing import Type

def fn(typ: Type):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify types, but you can signal the type using `arg: type` like this:

```py
def foo(a: str, b: int):
    # Stuff
    return a, b
```

Note that this won't prevent the user from doing something like `foo(a=1, b="2")` ... i.e., it won't throw an error because the types don't match.

Comment: i need to pass the class `int | str` as `parameter value`, not as `parameter type` (if it makes sense), i can type most variables using `Union | Literal | Any` but i am unable to use them for this purpose.